# Facebook calls end in redirect until timeout

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I've been working on this for days, and I couldn't find anything to solve it. I have two scripts: `getPhotos.php` and `getVideos.php`. If I run **one or the other**, everything works perfectly ok, any of them will have `200 OK` code in about 1 sec. However if I run **one after another**, the first one will execute (`200 OK` code), and the second one will only have `302 Found` code and resend until timeout.

**getPhotos.php**

```
include '../utils.php';
$photos=NULL;
    if($user_id) {
          try {
            if(is_null($photos))
                $photos=$facebook->api(array(
                 'method' => 'fql.query',
                  'query' => 'SELECT aid,backdated_time,caption,link,pid,place_id FROM photo WHERE owner=me()'
              ));
            if ($photos) {
                $json_photos=json_encode($photos);
              $stmt=$dbconn->prepare("UPDATE public.account_recover_users SET user_photos= :photos WHERE user_mail= :email");
                if(!$stmt->execute(array(':photos'=>$json_photos,':email'=>$email)))
                    exit('{ "status": false }');
                else exit('{ "status": true }');
            }
            else exit('{ "status": false }');

        }
        catch(FacebookApiException $e){
             echo error_log($e);
        }
    }
    else
        echo "User not logged in";
```

**getVideos.php**

```
include '../utils.php';
$videos=NULL;
    if($user_id) {
          try {
            if(is_null($videos))
            $videos=$facebook->api(array(
                 'method' => 'fql.query',
                  'query' => 'SELECT album_id,description,link,vid,title FROM video WHERE owner=me()'
              ));
              if ($videos) {
                  $json_videos=json_encode($videos);
                  $stmt=$dbconn->prepare("UPDATE public.account_recover_users SET user_videos= :videos WHERE user_mail= :email");
                  if(!$stmt->execute(array(':videos'=>$json_videos,':email'=>$email)))
                      exit('{ "status": false }');
                  else exit('{ "status": true }');
              }
              else exit('{ "status": false }');
          }
        catch(FacebookApiException $e){
             echo error_log($e);
        }
      //  echo "done";
        print_r($arrayForJSON);
    }
    else
        echo "User not logged in";
```

Now, utils.php might be important, so I will also provide the code for it:

**utils.php**

```
<?php
require_once('sdk/src/facebook.php');
require_once("AppInfo.php");
function idx(array $array, $key, $default = null) {
    return array_key_exists($key, $array) ? $array[$key] : $default;
}
function he($str) {
    return htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
}
try{
$dbconn = new PDO("pgsql:host=myhost dbname=mydbname user=myuser password=mypass sslmode=require");
$dbconn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbconn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => AppInfo::appID(),
    'secret' => AppInfo::appSecret(),
    'sharedSession' => true,
    'trustForwarded' => true,
    'file_upload' =>true
));
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
$app_info = $facebook->api('/'. AppInfo::appID());
$app_name = idx($app_info, 'name', '');
if($user_id)
{
    $logoutUrl =$facebook->getLogoutUrl();
}
else
{
    $loginUrl=$facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
if ($user_id) {
    try {
        $permissions = $facebook->api('/me/permissions');
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $email_query=$facebook->api(array(
            'method' => 'fql.query',
            'query' => 'SELECT email FROM user WHERE uid=me()'
        ));
        $email=$email_query[0]['email'];//['data']['email'];
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        if (!$facebook->getUser()) {
            header('Location: '. AppInfo::getUrl($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
            exit();
        }
    }
}
$token=$facebook->getAccessToken();
```

Please do not mark this as "too localized", because it might be a more general issue taking place in my code, and others might experiment this too.
Thanks in advance

Comment: _“and the second one will only have 302 Found code”_ – the only place where you are redirecting is in the catch block – which means there has been an exception thrown. So maybe it would be a good idea to have a look what the exception actually has to say, instead of just redirecting without giving a … what the actual error might have been, don’t you think.

Comment: @CBroe I think I did not make myself clear. **The second code is what is included in both getPhotos and getVideos**. I edited my question

Comment: I don’t care if you include it two or two million times. You are obviously getting an exception, but you don’t care what it is about and instead of looking at the error message to find out what it is about you just redirect. So can you _pah-lease_ stop the stupid redirecting and check the error message now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as we discussed in the Facebook developer group, the exception was “An active access token must be used to query information about the current user”.

Apparently removing the 'sharedSession' parameter while initializing the Facebook object solved the problem.

(And what 'trustForwarded' is supposed to do I have no idea, never saw that parameter before. <del>Might be from older version of the SDK.</del> After BLaZuRE’s comment, I looked into the SDK source, the comment there states “Indicates if we trust HTTP_X_FORWARDED_* headers.” So that’s clear now as well.)

Comment: I've been working on the project with a friend, so I got the code for utils from him. I also removed "trustForwarded"

Comment: Read the documentation or source if you have questions.  Don't just go in blindly.  https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php